# Source transformation: my analysis technique is off somehow

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image: figure1]

I am having a real hard time with these problems, I understand how to use ohms law to transform voltage sources in series with resistors into current sources in parallel with said resistors. For some reason though every time I try and do the transformations, I always end up with really weird numbers, even though as far as I and my tutor can tell, I'm doing perfectly valid transformations.

Is there some kind of rule I haven't come across regarding which sources should be transformed first or not? Even if this were the case, shouldn't the answers be the same in the end anyways, no matter which direction your math and analysis took?

The top circuit is the original in which I am to solve for current \$I_o\$ across the 1.5 ohm resistor. The middle work is my transformation giving me an answer of 0.31 A. The bottom portion is the answer from the solutions manual which comes out to an answer of -0.85A? How are my tutor and I not seeing where my math or analysis goes wrong? How do I prevent from starting my analysis down the wrong path of transforms?

Answer (score 1):

The book is correct; your solution is incorrect.  In the first diagram of your solution, the source being converted is in between nodes A and B.  In the second diagram, your equivalent source has moved to between nodes A and C, which is incorrect.  It should be as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Note that nodes A and C are not the same node; there is another power source on the left side of the circuit in between nodes A and C.